# Can not edit parameter in Read Database in RapidMiner 7

Tags: rapidminer

I drag a Read Database operator in the process view and then try to edit the parameter, but the parameter can not be edited as showing (btw, I already added a database connection in manage database connections):

Not sure how to solve the problem?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your view setup got a bit out of order. Try to click the little blue arrow on top of the Parameters tab, or even reset the complete view via RapidMiner's menu -> `View -> Restore Default View`.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BAPRx.png)